# submit button not changing colour on hover

Tags: html, css

I have a submit button in html that I want to change colour when I hover over it, but for some reason it won't change colour, my css and my html are below

```css
.submit:hover {
    background: #CF4647;;
}
```

```html
<td colspan="2" style="text-align:center" >
  <br /><br />
   <input type="submit" class="submit" value=" Send " style="width:200px;height:40px;background-color:#44c767;border-radius:25%;">
   <br /><br />
```

Comment: You have `sumbit:hover` but you probably meant `submit:hover`

Comment: that was just a typo when I put it on, it is written as submit:hover but it doesn't work

Comment: Right, I was just noting that, which is why I left it as a comment and not an answer

Comment: inline style always win the battle

Comment: just another thing, how would I make the mouse pointer change to a hand when hovering over this button

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to avoid inline styles (`style='xyz';`) as they take priority and will overwrite all other styles which don't have an `!important` flag (like your hover). 
Here's your code the way it should be written. As a bonus I've added a little fade transition to your button and changed the cursor to a hand pointer as you requested in a comment :)

```css
.submit{ width:200px; height:40px; background-color:#44c767; border-radius:25%; cursor:pointer; transition:background 300ms; }
.submit:hover {
    background: #CF4647;
}
```

```html
<td colspan="2" style="text-align:center" >
  <br /><br />
   <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Send">
   <br /><br />
</td>
```

Comment: it's not a spelling mistake and you completly changed the code and you didn't say why and what?

Comment: I just copied that into it and it came out like a default button and when you hover over it, it goes red

Comment: @TemaniAfifi, I've added an explanation for your approval. **Gavi** it should not look like a default button (try clicking "run code snippet" above to see how it should look). If it looks like a default button, there's something else in your project overwriting it.

Answer (score 1):

You had a typo, change .sumbit to .submit, also inline style have a higher priority, so move it outside

```css
.submit:hover {
    background-color: #CF4647;
}
.submit {
    background-color: #44c767;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<td colspan="2" style="text-align:center" >
  <br /><br />
   <input type="submit" class="submit" value=" Send " style="width:200px;height:40px;border-radius:25%;">
   <br /><br />
```

Comment: @Gavi you can use cursor: pointer on .submit to change the cursor

Comment: like this?.submit {
    background-color: #00FF00;cursor: pointer;
}

Comment: @Gavi np, glad i could help

Answer (score 1):

The *actual* reason your code isn't working (aside from the typo you originally had) is that your inline styling is overriding your CSS rules. Simply remove the inline style and make it a rule like your other CSS:

```css
.submit:hover {
  background: #CF4647;
}

.submit {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #44c767;
  border-radius: 25%;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" class="submit" value=" Send ">
```

This has to do with [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). As MDN says:

> Inline styles added to an element (e.g., style="font-weight:bold")
>   always overwrite any styles in external stylesheets, and thus can be
>   thought of as having the highest specificity.

Comment: and in case he cannot change/remove the inline style, he need to use !important

Comment: I copied this code and it has a default button now but goes red when you hover

Comment: @Gavi Well that's because that's the color you chose. You have `#CF4647` which is a shade of red